# 'my and (name)'... 'his and (name)'

Tags: possessive-determiners

This one has always bothered me.

Is this sentence correct?

> He shivered, thinking about **his** and Anya’s first time in the hospital.

It feels awkward, but there's a need to refer to their shared experience.

This would also apply to something like:

> I shivered, thinking about **mine** and Anya's first time in the hospital.

Again, it clunks, but I can't see an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct, but I agree that the second one in particular feels awkward.  I think the awkwardness comes from thinking about taking "and  Anya's" out of the second sentence, which would leave you with

*"I shivered, thinking about mine first time in the hospital."*

which is obviously not right - you'd say *"my first time"*.

Regardless of that, it's correct.

Comment: Shouldn't it be *my and Anya's*, not *mine and Anya's*.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Anya's and my first time?

Comment: After a bit of googling, this actually seems to be some dispute about this, and in fact some people recommend rephrasing the sentence to avoid the problem completely.

Comment: @mplungjan I think that's an acceptable alternative, though personally it feels a little bit more awkward.  That might just be my opinion.

Comment: I was taught to always mention the woman first

Comment: @mplungjan that's interesting, as a point of protocol, but I don't believe that rule is part of the language.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the second one feels really awkward.

If you need to refer to their shared experience, and you have also mentioned about it before, or you are already talking about both people involved(in your case, Anya and you...) than you can also use 'their' as below:

He shivered, thinking about their first time in the hospital.

or

I shivered, thinking about our first time in the hospital.